# How to top-up a panel survey to also get population estimates

Tags: sampling, panel-data, stata, survey-sampling, non-response

I'm running two sequential surveys on the same population, and I have a question about the proper sampling methodology in the second round of a panel that is also meant to get population estimates. I work more in Python but I will likely do this in Stata.

First round is actually done, but let's keep it and say I run simple random samples with 50% response rate (never mind power/size for now). In the first survey I drew 800 and settled for n=400. I used it to achieve estimates about the population. I'd like to do a second survey now. The purpose is to (A) get new population estimates and (B) get panel data for a separate analysis. For purpose (A) I need n=400, and for purpose (B) I'd like to call back the same 400 respondents as in the first survey. If I call back my previous sample of n=400, at 50% RR I'll get n=200 in my panel (which is fine), but I'll need 200 new respondents to reach n=400 for the new population estimates. What's the right sampling technique for second survey?

My guess is that I just use the same random seed that I used to draw respondents 1-800 in the first round, but this time I continue to draw respondents 801-1200. At 50% RR, I'll add n=200 new respondents to the n=200 in the panel. From the total draw of 1200, 800 would be considered nonrespondents when calculating the new population estimates. Am I on track with this approach or totally wrong?

My main concern is that in round two I'm not re-dialing the 400 NON-respondents from the first round, and this seems wrong since they don't have a chance of selection in round two. Perhaps I should give them a chance to be re-drawn in the new survey, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I haven't messaged here much, so apologies if I've abused etiquette in any way.

Thank you!